# Why do < and > need to be escaped in preg_*() patterns?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've run `preg_quote('<>')` to check if these characters need to be escaped in a regular expression, and to my surprise, they came back escaped: `\<\>`.

**Why do these characters need to be escaped?** What is their meaning in a regular expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<` has significance when used to define lookbehinds
(`(?<!foo)bar` matches `bar` that is not preceded by `foo`)

Both `<` and `>` are used to name subpatterns, like so:

```
preg_match("/(?<area>\d{3})-(?<sub>\d{3})-(?<num>\d{4})/",$number,$m);
// now elements of the US phone number are in $m['area'], $m['sub'] and $m['num']
```

So, because they can have significance when used in conjunction with other symbols, they are escaped.

It should be noted, however, that they have no meaning outside of a specific place in a subpattern, so if you're escaping manually you most likely won't need to escape them.

---

To expand further:

[The documentation](http://php.net/preg-quote) has a full list of characters that are escaped. Here I will list them, along with their meanings.

- `.` Match any single character, other than newlines (unless the `s` modifier is set)
- `\` Escape the following character, or begin an escape sequence
- `+` Match one or more of the preceding character, class, or subpattern
- `*` Match zero or more of the preceding character, class, or subpattern
- `?` Makes the previous item optional, also used in subpatterns to define special behaviours such as "don't capture" (`(?:foo)`), "lookahead" (`(?=foo)` and `(?!foo)`), "lookbehind" (`(?<=foo)` and `(?<!foo)`), and many other uses besides.
- `[` and `]` Define a character class, ie. a set of characters that may be matched. Most other symbols don't have meaning inside character classes.
- `^` and `$` Match the start and end of the string respecively. When the `m` modifier is present, it also matches the start and end of individual lines.
- `(` and `)` Define a subpattern, used alone for capturing or with `?` for special behaviour. Also useful for applying quantifiers, such as in `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*` to match thousand-separated numbers.
- `{` and `}` Manually quantify the previous item. Takes one or two numbers, separated by a comma. Examples include `{3}` to match exactly three times, `{,3}` to match zero to three times, `{3,}` to match three or more times, and `{3,8}` to match three to eight times.
- `=` Used in lookahead assertions: `foo(?=bar)` matches `foo`, but only if it is followed by `bar`.
- `!` Used in negative lookaround assertions: `foo(?!bar)` matches `foo`, but not if it is followed by `bar`.
- `<` and `>` The subject of this question, see the start of the answer for info.
- `|` Alternation, specifying a list of possibilities. It's kind of like a character class but for entire patterns instead of single characters. `foo|bar` matches "foo" or "bar". May also be seen as a special behaviour in subpatterns: `(?|foo(bar)|bar(foo))` ensures that whatever bit falls in the parentheses will be in subpattern 1 (otherwise, `bar` would be in 1 if matched, `foo` would be in 2 if matched, and the unmatched one would be empty)
- `:` Used in subpatterns to make them non-capturing. Essentially, the subpattern just becomes a "group of characters", which will typically be quantified. `(?:foo)` matches, but does not capture, "foo".
- `-` Defines a range of characters in a character class. Has no meaning outside of one.

Comment: And of course we should always remember, don't try and parse HTML with regular expressions :)